# One To Many relationship codeigniter/datamapper

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

I need help on this plz :

2 tables

Service : has many Sub_Service
Sub_Service : has one Service

My code :

```
    $services = new Service();
    $services->where('org_id', $org_id)->get();
    $services->sub_service->get();

    foreach($services as $service)
    {
        echo $service->title;

        foreach($service->sub_service as $sub_service)
        {
                  echo $sub_service->title;
        }
    }
```

But it doesn’t work, if I want to access sub_service i have to take it out of the first loop and do somthing like

```
foreach($services->sub_service as $sub_service)
            {
                   echo $sub_service->title;
            }
```

But this is not what I want, i want to get an array like this one :

Service 1

—Subservice 1

—Subservice 3

Service 2

Service 3

—Subservice 2

Info i’m using DM 1.8 and CI2.

Thx for ur help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the 'all' property available in datamapper objects

```
foreach($services->all as $service)
{
    echo $service->title;

    foreach($service->sub_service->all as $sub_service)
    {
              echo $sub_service->title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the include_join_fields method of datamapper in order to create the relationship as you want it. In your controller, include this:

```
$service = new Service();
$data = $service->get(); 
$options['records'] = $data;
```

and then in your view you can do this:

```
    if(isset($records)){

    foreach($records as $service){

            echo $service->title;
        $subservice = $service->subservice->include_join_fields()->get();

        foreach($subservise as $subservice){
            if(!is_null($subservice->title)){  
                echo $subservice->title;
            }
        }

    }
```

This will give you what you want.